# georeferencing swisstopo print

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

when i tried to georeference a printout from [map.geo.admin.ch](http://map.geo.admin.ch), either the result got turned some degrees, or the height got compressed or both.

using the helmert transformation gave me the best results. the result was not compressed - only rotated.

it then looks like:
[image]

the coordinates for the reference points i userd were taken from the coordinate grid on the website. i used the four corners.
top left: 46.86851  9.99669
bottom left: 46.76063   9.99157
bottom right: 46.75528  10.22048
top right: 46.86315 10.22609

i tried it with a screenshot of google maps with the same results...
is there a way to georeference that print without rotating it?

Comment: Can you add how you picked your coordinates, and what CRS settings you have used?

Comment: Why georeference a TIFF when you can use a WMS or WMTS ? www.swisstopo.ch/webaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The website lets you choose between CH1903+LV95, WGS84, UTM and MGRS coordinates.

Since the map is originally in CH1903+, I suggest to use that CRS and the meter coordinates of it. You can choose to imprint a coordinate grid, which is also in CH1903.

You have to set EPSG:2056 in the georeferencer settings dialogue.

In the part of Switzerland you downloaded, the CH1903 grid is rotated against the degree grid, so that is why you get a rotated image in degree coordinates.

Comment: thanks!
i did use CRS CH1903+, but added the coordinates as wgs84.
as you suggested, i used the meter coordinates now, but the raster got streched now (in contrast to beeing compressed before)...

Comment: also, when i used WGS84, the raster was compressed, but it showed my location accurately (using my maps for android) - now, with meter coordinates, the app says my location is not on the map...

Comment: please ignore both my comments - i noticed, in the WGS84 format, they use North/East, but in CH1903+ they use East/North... now it works.

Comment: @marcin you can still delete your comments if you realize you thought wrong.